# Moving from typings to @types in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Getting rid off the typings configuration and adding @types instead has produced a series of errors while compiling the project. Apparently @types/core-js can be seen by the typescript compiler and VS IntelliSense.

Here an example of one of the many errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Set'. TypeScript Virtual Projects C:\Projects\Cool\Project\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts  46  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects C:\Projects\Cool\Project\node_modules\@angular\common\src\pipes\async_pipe.d.ts 44  Active
```

**Set** and **Promise** are defined by core-js

Following **package.json** configuration

```
"name": "Cool",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/mcustomscrollbar": "^2.8.30",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "~3.1.5",
    "material-design-iconic-font": "~2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {        
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "typescript": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Here is the **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./Scripts/app",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]            
  },
  "exclude": [

  ],
  "files": [
    "./Scripts/src/main.ts" 
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are using TypeScript 2?

Comment: @TGH, first thing I did this morning. I have TypeScript 1.8. I will upgrade it and post my comments. Thanks

Comment: Yes!!! Life is good when everything works man!. Installed tsc 2.0.6 for visual studio 2015. When I opened the project, VS asked me to switch to the newer version of tsc. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I had tsc 1.8. By installing tsc 2.0.x all compiling errors went away. Thanks.